# Visual Studio 2013 cant connect to sharepoint site, on same server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, farm-solution

i have a problem, sorry for my english. 
I have a virtual server where I have installed SharePoint 2013 Enterprise, SQL Server 2012 R2 and Visual Studio 2013.
When opening visual studio 2013 and trying to create a sharepoint solution, this one displays me an error box, stating "Can not connect to the target site, this error can occur the specified site not being hosted on the local system." .
And I can not find the solution, if you need additional information, I can add it in the question
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a hypen in your URL (spc-sharepoint**-**:8080). Remove that and try again.

EDIT:
You need to modify the hosts file at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` with the line:

`127.0.0.1 spc-sharepoint-`

Comment: The character '-' is part of the server name

Comment: The next step would be to add a hosts file entry in the format of 127.0.0.1 spc-sharepoint- on the SharePoint server itself.

Comment: Sorry, have to add the ip 127.0.0.1 or ip from the same server (10.10.1.1xx) ?

Comment: You need to modify the hosts file at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` with the line:

`127.0.0.1 spc-sharepoint-`

Comment: i need restart the server?

Comment: It doesn't require a restart, but you should close out VS and reopen it after making the change.